# If item in list does not contain "string", add a "string2" to the item?

Tags: python, list

In Python I have a list of this sort:

```
list = ["item.1", "sdfhkjdsffs/THIS-STRING", "fsdhfjsdhfsdf/THIS-STRING",
        item4/THIS-STRING, item5]
```

How do I go about adding `"some string"` for each item in list that does *not* contain `"THIS-STRING"`?

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to replace "THIS-STRING" with "some string" or do you want to add "some string" as an element?

Comment: I mean if item in list does not contain "THIS-STRING" than add "different-string" to that item. so with above example item.1 will become item.1different-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = [x if x.find("SOME-STRING")>=0 else x+"some string" for x in list]
```

Comment: i get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Does your list have lists in it?

Comment: 1 list containing items

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. Your last 2 items listed in your example don't have quotes around them, I assumed you wanted these as strings so I added them as strings, and what I wrote worked on that example. The error message makes it sound like you have a nested list. If so you will need to either ignore the sub-lists or create a recursive solution.